# How does TezEdge achieve parallelism?

Tags: node, shell

I am researching on how to parallelize transaction validation in Tezos, and I came across [TezEdge](https://docs.tezedge.com/get-started/quick-start) and [this blog](https://medium.com/viablesystems/the-tezedge-node-using-multiple-cpu-cores-to-pre-validate-operations-in-tezos-eb4d26dc3b7d).

Both of these articles mention that they use OCaml Runtime FFI Pools, but my primary concern is about transaction dependency, which prevents us from executing in parallel. Indeed there are techniques using software transactional memory to detect these dependencies and execute in parallel (see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00446-019-00357-z)) however it is not clear how TezEdge is achieving parallelism. Does anyone have any insights in this area?

Thanks in advance.